# Page not found (404) Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/about

Tags: python, django

error is when http://127.0.0.1:8000/about
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/about
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

The current path, about, didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

projets

mysite urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('',include('mainapp.urls')),

]
```

main app urls.py

```
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path('',views.home),
path('about',views.about),
path('contact',views.contact)
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,HttpResponse

def home(request):
return render(request,"index.html")

def about(request):
return render(request,"about.html")

def contact(request):
return render(request,"contact.html")
```

templates/about.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document1</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Mahabir pun</h1>
<p>he is a great person he is a doing grat</p>

</body>
```

how to solve please help me i am in trouble for 2 days

Comment: Your error message doesn't have the patterns that are tried by Django, that's weird!!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you added 'mainapp' to 'INSTALLED_APPS' in your project's 'settings.py'?

Answer (score 0):

try adding the slashes

```
path('about/',views.about),
path('contact/',views.contact)
```

and then you can try

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/about/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your URL Patterns does not have a name inside the path. Do the following changes and let me know.

```
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
path('',views.home, name='home'),
path('about',views.about, name='about'),
path('contact',views.contact, name='contact')
]
```

The name inside the path is link name which should also be used in the anchor href. e.g.  for the home page link and so on for the other pages links too. Thanks